# Detecting and assigning NA values in an R vector when using C

Tags: r

I'm using R's .Call interface to C to pass and return real-valued vectors (REALSXP) which may include NA values. For vectors being passed into C, I need to detect the existence of NA values, and in vectors which I return from C I need to assign the NA value.

Suppose `vec` is a `SEXP` object that has been set equal to a vector containing `REALSXP` objects. For instance, if allocating this in C, the code might be

```
SEXP vec;
PROTECT(vec = allocVector(REALSXP, 10));
```

With respect to detecting an NA value, I know the following will work:

```
isnan(vec[index])
```

where `isnan()` is defined in `math.h`. Is this the preferred way for detecting NA values?

I do not know how to assign NA values. I know that I can do something like the following,

```
vec[index] = 0.0/0.0;
```

to assign an NaN. I'm not sure exactly what the difference is between NaN and NA in R, but I would prefer to assign NA instead of NaN.

**EDIT**

Found the answer. Functions `ISNA()` and `ISNAN()` are defined in R_ext/Arith.h and so is the symbol `R_NaReal` which can be used to assign an NA value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer to my question. Functions `ISNA()` and `ISNAN()` are defined in R_ext/Arith.h and so is the symbol `R_NaReal` which can be used to assign an NA value.